# Error in simplifying $\frac{\tan x+\sec x-1}{\tan x-\sec x+1}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

[image]

I know that my solution is wrong because for $x = 0^\circ,$ the results are not the same. Where did I go wrong?

Comment: Your work is correct. It's just that the given expression is undefined for $x=2k\pi$ and $x=\pi/2+k\pi, k\in\mathbb{Z}$ so you can't plug in $x=0^{\circ}$ or $x=90^{\circ}$. Try plugging in anything else for which the expression is defined, for instance $x=30^{\circ}$.

Comment: Your first step falsely assumes that $x$ cannot be $180^\circ;$ your final step drops the implicit condition that $x$ cannot be $0^\circ.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The given expression $$\frac{\tan x+\sec x-1}{\tan x-\sec x +1}\tag
       L$$ has the implicit condition $$\tan x-\sec
       x+1\ne0\quad\text{AND}\quad\cos x\ne0\\ \cos x-\sin
       x\ne1\quad\text{AND}\quad \cos x\ne0\\
       \sqrt2\cos\left(x+\frac\pi4\right)\ne1\quad\text{AND}\quad 
       x\ne2n\pi\pm\frac\pi2\\ x\ne2n\pi\:\text{ or }\:(2n\pm1)
       \frac\pi2,$$ whereas your new expression $$\tan x+\sec x\tag R$$ has
   the implicit condition $$\cos x\ne0\\ x\ne(2n\pm1) \frac\pi2.$$

   In fact, the identity $$\frac{\tan x+\sec x-1}{\tan x-\sec x
   +1}\equiv\tan x+\sec x$$ has domain $$\mathbb R{\setminus}\left\{x:\exists n{\in}\mathbb Z\:\:x= 2n\pi\:\text{ or
   }\:(2n\pm1)\frac\pi2\right\}.$$
2. In your first step, you carelessly introduced the restriction $$\tan
   x+\sec x+1\ne0;$$ then in the final step, you invalidly discarded
   the restriction $$\tan x\ne0;$$ these missteps in your
   simplification ultimately expanded the domain by adding the even
   multiples of $\pi$ to it.